# No options to pass the bulk data from one page to another page

Tags: admin-on-rest

I have a list page with checkbox where we can select all the rows by using global checkbox or single row by using each row checkbox. I have button at top right corner CUSTOM ACTION which would take us to another page.

So After the select the rows from list, When I click CUSTOM ACTION button, I wanted all the selected rows ID's in next page.

[Here is example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mB9LZ.png)

Comment: Read up about creating custom Redux Reducers in AOR and then just write your selected rows into the state. Just query that part of state on redirect to new page.

Comment: See how admin-on-rest implemented bulk actions in the `next` branch: https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/pull/1521